# Extract the lowest and highest value from a measurement range - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a table that contains measurements. This table has a field calledrange, from which I would like tocreate two new columns with the minimum and maximum values of the range. When one end of the interval is missing, it can take the value null.

**For example:** The table

| id | range |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 - 150 |
| 2 | > 35 |
| 3 | < 90 |
| 4 | 6,4 - 8,3 |

should become

| id | range | low | high |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 - 150 | 40 | 150 |
| 2 | > 35 | 35 | null |
| 3 | < 90 | null | 90 |
| 4 | 6,4 - 8,3 | 6,4 | 8,3 |

I tried to extract the required information with regex, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has range types. Using it you could easily specify lower, upper bounds and their inclusivity. Also range type has functions and operators to work with that range type, plus you could easily merge multi ranges, postgreSQL handling overlaps for you etc. Also it makes sense to use +-infinity instead of null.

[PostgreSQL Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

Anyway you decide to use range type or two columns:

```
create table ranges (id int,    "range" varchar(10));
insert into ranges (id, "range") values 
(1, '40 - 150'),
(2, '> 35'),
(3, '< 90'),
(4, '6,4 - 8,3');

select *
  from ranges, lateral 
  (select case 
  when "range" like '>%' then replace(replace("range",',','.'),'>','(') || ', infinity]' 
  when "range" like '<%' then '[-infinity,' || replace(replace("range",',','.'),'<','') || ')'
  else '[' || replace(replace("range",',','.'),'-',',') || ']'
  end::numrange) r(myrange),
  lateral (select lower(myrange), upper(myrange)) b(low,high);
```

| id | range | myrange | low | high |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 - 150 | [40,150] | 40 | 150 |
| 2 | > 35 | (35,Infinity] | 35 | Infinity |
| 3 | < 90 | [-Infinity,90) | -Infinity | 90 |
| 4 | 6,4 - 8,3 | [6.4,8.3] | 6.4 | 8.3 |

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vQtHoVDA)